# Selenium: list index out of range Error

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Error whenever i am trying to run this code. i am just trying to print all the URL's on this page. Can please someone tell me ,what i am doing wrong??

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.tour-india.net/best-of-india.htm")
cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
for i in range(0,len(cities)):
    cities1=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")[i]
    cities1.click()
    title=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//title")
    content=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tours_text_innerpage.content_margin_top")
    currentUrl=browser.current_url
    print currentUrl
    browser.back()
```

Edit:
 I was making some modifications in the code
I added **cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")** again after for loop and suddenly Index Error stopped coming. Now i am confused why it happened.??

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.tour-india.net/best-of-india.htm")
cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
for i in range(0,len(cities)):
    cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
    cities1=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")[i]
    cities1.click()
    title=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//title")
    content=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tours_text_innerpage.content_margin_top")
    currentUrl=browser.current_url
    print currentUrl
    browser.back()
```

Edit: my Entire Traceback

```
>>> import traceback
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.get("http://www.tour-india.net/best-of-india.htm")
>>> cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
>>> for i in range(0,len(cities)):      
...     try:
...             #cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
...             cities1=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")[i]
...             cities1.click()
...             title=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//title")
...             content=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tours_text_innerpage.content_margin_top")
...             currentUrl=browser.current_url
...             print currentUrl
...             browser.back()
...     except:
...             print traceback.format_exc()
... 
http://www.tour-india.net/golden-triangle.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/golden-triangle-varanasi.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/magnificent-rajasthan.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/northindia-rajasthan-tour.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/north_india_himalaya_tour.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

http://www.tour-india.net/southindia-panorma.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/classical-rajasthan-tours.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/rajasthan-forts.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/india-nepal-tour.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/southindia-glimpses.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/enchanting-southindia.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/shekhawati-tours.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/delhi-tour.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/bombay-goa.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/royal-rajasthan.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/grand-mughal.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/north_india_himalaya_tour.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/northindia-images.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/karnataka-heritage.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/leh-ladakh.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

http://www.tour-india.net/darjeeling-sikkim.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/himalayan-heritage.htm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

http://www.tour-india.net/rajasthan-goa.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/rajasthan-forts-palaces.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/rajasthan-mp.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/rajasthan-nepal.htm
http://www.tour-india.net/splendid-gujarat.htm
```

Comment: which line does the original error traceback to? (I don't see how it can be line 2?)

Comment: @hayden Actually it's random. it is coming at any line that's why it is so confusing.Just try to run it at your console.

Comment: do you think you could you post the entire traceback?

Comment: @hayden I tried to print the entire traceback but all it is printing what i have mentioned

Comment: can you not highlight it in the terminal (or wherever) and copy and paste it?

Comment: @hayden Please check the entire output of the script.I have pasted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling cities variable again after cities solved the problem.Still i don't know why.but it is working fine.Since nobody posted the answer. Accepting my own answer

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.tour-india.net/best-of-india.htm")
cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
for i in range(0,len(cities)):
    cities=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")
    cities1=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".posts1>a>h2")[i]
    cities1.click()
    title=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//title")
    content=browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".tours_text_innerpage.content_margin_top")
    currentUrl=browser.current_url
    print currentUrl
    browser.back(
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you click every link, print it, and go back?  This is awfully inefficient.  You can get the url of all the links on a page very quickly by using the .get_attribute method.

```
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')]
for i in links:
    print i
```

will print a list of all the links on a page.  To select a smaller area of the page, find the 'frame' element that you want to select from, and use

```
frame.find_elements_by_xpath('//a')
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `len(cities)-1`, `len` returns 1 more than length of the list as Python sees it.

Comment: i think you are saying len(cities)-1, cities is not a length .its an array and in your case the error would be for last item. but it is happening for random element.

Answer (score -3):

```
for i in range(len(cities)):
```

Range takes only one argument:)

you can modify your loop:

```
for city in cities:
    city.click()
    # rest is the same
```

It's more "pythonic"

Comment: `range()` takes up to 3 arguments... http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range